# letsencrypt misconfuration on mulitdomains on serverpilot digitalocean

Tags: digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I've got serverpilot running on a digital ocean droplet.

Ubuntu 14.04

I've followed the tutorial: https://bjoernfranzen.com/how-to-set-up-a-letsencrypt-ssl-certificate-for-your-wordpress-website-on-a-digital-ocean-server-managed-with-a-serverpilot-free-account/

And it worked perfectly for the first domain.

The second domain following the same setup has issues.

Chrome says

"This server cannot prove that it is domain2; its security certificate is from domain1. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection"

Answer (score 0):

This error means that SSL installation wasn't succeeded and you made a mistake somewhere. [This shell script](https://github.com/rehmatworks/serverpilot-letsencrypt) automates the installation of the SSL on your all ServerPilot apps.

To avoid any troubles for the users, I'm pasting the snippet here as well along with the instructions how to install the SSL:

```
#!/bin/bash
#################################################
#                       
#   This script automates the installation  
#   of Let's Encrypt SSL certificates on    
#   your ServerPilot free plan      
#                       
#################################################


theAction=$1
domainName=$2
appName=$3
spAppRoot="/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/$appName"
domainType=$4
spSSLDir="/etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/"
# Install Let's Encrypt libraries if not found
if ! hash letsencrypt 2>/dev/null; then
    lecheck=$(eval "apt-cache show letsencrypt 2>&1")
    if [[ "$lecheck" == *"No"* ]]
        then
        sudo wget --no-check-certificate https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto  &>/dev/null
        sudo chmod a+x certbot-auto  &>/dev/null
        sudo mv certbot-auto /usr/local/bin/letsencrypt  &>/dev/null
    else
        sudo apt-get install -y letsencrypt  &>/dev/null
    fi
fi

if [ -z "$theAction" ]
    then
    echo -e "\e[31mPlease specify the task. Should be either install or uninstall\e[39m"
    exit
fi

if [ -z "$domainName" ]
    then
    echo -e "\e[31mPlease provide the domain name\e[39m"
    exit
fi

if [ ! -d "$spAppRoot" ]
    then
    echo -e "\e[31mThe app name seems invalid as we didn't find its directory on your server\e[39m"
    exit 
fi

if [ -z "$appName" ]
    then
    echo -e "\e[31mPlease provide the app name\e[39m"
    exit
fi

if [ "$theAction" == "uninstall" ]; then
    sudo rm "$spSSLDir$appName-ssl.conf" &>/dev/null
    sudo service nginx-sp reload
    echo -e "\e[31mSSL has been removed. If you are seeing errors on your site, then please fix HTACCESS file and remove the rules that you added to force SSL\e[39m"
elif [ "$theAction" == "install" ]; then
    if [ -z "$domainType" ]
        then
        echo -e "\e[31mPlease provide the type of the domain (either main or sub)\e[39m"
        exit
    fi
    sudo service nginx-sp stop
    echo -e "\e[32mChecks passed, press enter to continue\e[39m"
    if [ "$domainType" == "main" ]; then
        thecommand="letsencrypt certonly --register-unsafely-without-email --agree-tos -d $domainName -d www.$domainName"
    elif [[ "$domainType" == "sub" ]]; then
        thecommand="letsencrypt certonly --register-unsafely-without-email --agree-tos -d $domainName"
    else
        echo -e "\e[31mDomain type not provided. Should be either main or sub\e[39m"
        exit
    fi
    output=$(eval $thecommand 2>&1) | xargs

    if [[ "$output" == *"too many requests"* ]]; then
        echo "Let's Encrypt SSL limit reached. Please wait for a few days before obtaining more SSLs for $domainName"
    elif [[ "$output" == *"Congratulations"* ]]; then
    
    if [ "$domainType" == "main" ]; then
        sudo echo "server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name
    $domainName
    www.$domainName
    ;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/privkey.pem;

    root $spAppRoot/public;

    access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/$appName/dev_nginx.access.log main;
    error_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/$appName/dev_nginx.error.log;

    proxy_set_header Host \$host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;

    include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/$appName.d/*.nonssl_conf;
    include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/$appName.d/*.conf;
}" > "$spSSLDir$appName-ssl.conf"

    elif [ "$domainType" == "sub" ]; then
        sudo echo "server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name
    $domainName
    ;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/privkey.pem;

    root $spAppRoot/public;

    access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/$appName/dev_nginx.access.log main;
    error_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/$appName/dev_nginx.error.log;

    proxy_set_header Host \$host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;

    include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/$appName.d/*.nonssl_conf;
    include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/$appName.d/*.conf;
}" > "$spSSLDir$appName-ssl.conf"
    fi

        echo -e "\e[32mSSL should have been installed for $domainName with auto-renewal (via cron)\e[39m"

        # Add a cron job for auto-ssl renewal
        grep "sudo service nginx-sp stop && yes | letsencrypt renew &>/dev/null && service nginx-sp start && service nginx-sp reload" /etc/crontab || sudo echo "@monthly sudo service nginx-sp stop && yes | letsencrypt renew &>/dev/null && service nginx-sp start && service nginx-sp reload" >> /etc/crontab
    elif [[ "$output" == *"Failed authorization procedure."* ]]; then
        echo -e "\e[31m$domainName isn't being resolved to this server. Please check and update the DNS settings if necessary and try again when domain name points to this server\e[39m"
    elif [[ ! $output ]]; then
        # If no output, we will assume that a valid SSL already exists for this domain
        # so we will just add the vhost
        sudo echo "server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name
    $domainName
    www.$domainName
    ;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domainName/privkey.pem;

    root $spAppRoot/public;

    access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/$appName/dev_nginx.access.log main;
    error_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/$appName/dev_nginx.error.log;

    proxy_set_header Host \$host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;

    include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/$appName.d/*.nonssl_conf;
    include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/$appName.d/*.conf;
}" > "$spSSLDir$appName-ssl.conf"
    echo -e "\e[32mSSL should have been installed for $domainName with auto-renewal (via cron)\e[39m"
        grep "sudo service nginx-sp stop && yes | letsencrypt renew &>/dev/null && service nginx-sp start && service nginx-sp reload" /etc/crontab || sudo echo "@monthly sudo service nginx-sp stop && yes | letsencrypt renew &>/dev/null && service nginx-sp start && service nginx-sp reload" >> /etc/crontab
    else
        echo -e "\e[31mSomething unexpected occurred\e[39m"
    fi 
    sudo service nginx-sp start && sudo service nginx-sp reload
else
    echo -e "\e[31mTask cannot be identified. It should be either install or uninstall \e[39m"
fi
```

**Usage:**
First of all, copy this code to /usr/local/bin/rwssl and make it executable (`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rwssl`). After that, you can run these commands to perform the actions:

**To Install the SSL**

For main domain:
`rwssl install example.com app_name main`

For a sub domain:
`rwssl install sub.example.com app_name main`

P.S.: I'm the project owner.